# How do I change only one image out of many onclick with appendChild?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, appendchild

I'm currently learning JavaScript at my university, so I apologize if my code is terrible. I'm new to it.

I'm having an issue only changing one image onclick using appendChild. What I want to happen is that if the person clicks on the image whose rng is <= 0.89, then only that image is changed to a different image. Every thing I've tried has changed all of the images whose rng was <=0.89.

Example: I click the first image (img1) which has rolled a number greater than 0.9. If (img2) has rolled the same (greater than 0.9), then it also changes. I'd only want img1 to change. Here is only some of my code as the whole thing is about 150 lines and I think this bit gets my point across somewhat well:

```
function myFunction() {
var rng=Math.random();
var rng2=Math.random();
if (rng <= 0.89){
  var img1=document.createElement('img');
  img1.src='card2.gif';
  img1.id="bad1"; 
  img1.onclick = goodbye;
  document.getElementById('card').appendChild(img1);
}
if (rng2 <= 0.89){
  var img2=document.createElement('img');
  img2.src='card2.gif';
  img2.onclick= goodbye;
  img2.id="bad2";
  document.getElementById('card2').appendChild(img2);
  }
if (rng >= 0.9) {
  var img1=document.createElement('img');
  img1.src='card3.gif';
  img1.id="good1"; 
  img1.onclick = hello;
  document.getElementById('card').appendChild(img1);
}
if (rng2 >= 0.9){
  var img2=document.createElement('img');
  img2.src='card3.gif';
  img2.onclick= hello;
  img2.id="good2";
  document.getElementById('card2').appendChild(img2);
  }
}
```

Like I said, every thing I've tried to only change the image that was clicked has changed all images whose rng is <=0.89. The answer's probably really obvious, but I'm new to this, like I said.

Comment: So you already have an element calling `myFunction()` when they click. Then inside u calculate a random number, if it meets the condition append a new `img` element. And ur  issue is its always going to the <= 0.89 only and not others ?

Comment: The random number generator works fine, it produces the images I want it to produce based on the numbers it rolls. myFunction() is called onLoad. My issue is with having an onclick event changing only the picture that was clicked on. I can't figure out how to do that, as everything I've tried has ended up changing all images that have rolled the same number group. Example: I click the first image (img1) which has rolled a number greater than 0.9. If (img2) has rolled the same (greater than 0.9), then it also changes. I'd only want img1 to change.

Comment: Can you check this jsfiddle and tell me if this is what you are doing https://jsfiddle.net/c4f1bkua/1/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. So to use your jsfiddle as an example, say they both rolled the twitter images. If I click on only one of the twitter images, I would want that twitter image _only_ to change into, say, a tumblr logo. And if one rolled a facebook logo, that would image only would change into a YouTube logo when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the only change that your code needs is to make `.onclick` set to a function instead of a string. This way we also pass `this` the element reference to your functions `goodbye` and `hello`. You can also use `this` to read the element properties if you wanted to. If this is not what your looking for let us know.

`img1.onclick = function(){goodbye(this)};`

Script

```
function goodbye(e) {
    e.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-logo-full_color.png'
}

function hello(e) {
    e.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/767879603977191425/29zfZY6I.jpg'
}

function myFunction() {
    var rng = Math.random();
    var rng2 = Math.random();
    if (rng <= 0.89) {
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');
        img1.src = 'card2.gif';
        img1.id = "bad1";
        img1.onclick = function () {
            goodbye(this)
        };
        document.getElementById('card').appendChild(img1);
    }
    if (rng2 <= 0.89) {
        var img2 = document.createElement('img');
        img2.src = 'card2.gif';
        img2.onclick = function () {
            goodbye(this)
        };
        img2.id = "bad2";
        document.getElementById('card2').appendChild(img2);
    }
    if (rng >= 0.9) {
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');
        img1.src = 'card3.gif';
        img1.id = "good1";
        img1.onclick = function () {
            hello(this)
        };
        document.getElementById('card').appendChild(img1);
    }
    if (rng2 >= 0.9) {
        var img2 = document.createElement('img');
        img2.src = 'card3.gif';
        img2.onclick = function () {
            hello(this)
        };
        img2.id = "good2";
        document.getElementById('card2').appendChild(img2);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4f1bkua/3/) if required